# Customize SP list with Power apps

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp

I have created a SP list and customized with Power Apps.
I have look up fields, which I changed to Dropdowns.

When I am trying to Update datacards, I do not seem to get form to fill columns.
Can anyone assist?

Datacard formula:
'Update'= Dropdown1.Selected.Result

see picture to see image with error.

[image: error picture]

Comment: Is the look-up column refer to the result column in that source list? Try with Dropdown1.selected.<columnName>

Comment: For some reason, it does not allow to select column name after selected.
This is very strange :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For lookup column, please try with the formula like below:

```
{
  Id: Value(Dropdown2.Selected.ID),
  Value: Value(Dropdown2.Selected.<ColumnName>)
}
```

I guess you remove the original data card and add a new dropdown for this whole data card. It works in my demo.

[image]